# How does the port mapping done between docker-for-windows and WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, port, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I have WSL2 with ubuntu 18.04 distribution in my Windows 10 pro.
I have docker-desktop installed which uses WSL2 based engine, and WSL integration enabled for this distro.

For example, I am creating a docker container that has port-mapping 8080:80.
That means, port 80 of the container is mapped to the host-port (windows host-port) 8080. Right?

When the container is up, the curl in the below scenarios works fine :

```
# From windows command prompt
curl http://localhost:8080/

# From WSL2 bash
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

When you type localhost in Windows command prompt, it is the Windows 10 machine(IP).

> WSL 2 uses a lightweight utility VM on a real Linux kernel with a
> small memory footprint, that is managed and run behind the scenes.

So, when you type localhost in WSL2, it is the WSL2 VM(IP).

Both IPs are different. Then how the magic happens that `localhost:8080` from both terminals are able to connect to the correct port?

What happens behind the scenes when you create a docker container (with port-mapping) in WSL2?

How the networking is done in this case between docker containers, windows host and WSL2 VM?